# Disable/Hide "Download the React DevTools..."

Tags: reactjs

How do you completely disable or hide the "persistent" console message: `Download the React DevTools for a better development experience` while in development?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As of React 16.2.0, you can add a line like this to your webpack configuration:

```
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    '__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__': '({ isDisabled: true })'
  }),
```

If not using webpack you can put, somewhere in a module imported before react:

```
window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = { isDisabled: true };
```

This disables all logs about React DevTools.

Comment: For those using `create-react-app`, as of this writing this may be added to the `plugins` section of `/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` in your project directory.

Comment: This is just too much. It disables the dev tools completely. We just want the stupid ad to disappear from the console. I use the dev tools but I don't want to read the ad message all the time when I'm running my browser tests which run on a fresh chromium (and locally not in prod mode, so the message appears). How do you just disable that ad message?

Comment: Where do you put this snippet? I'm getting `ReferenceError: webpack is not defined`

Comment: this didn't disable react devtools for me

Comment: is there a new way of disabling this annoying text? This answer is not valid anymore @Dan Abramov?

Comment: How to add this in a nextjs project?

Answer (score 8):

Put this line somewhere in the global scope (it won't work if you put it inside a bundled module):

```
__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = true;
```

Here's a related [gist](https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/1030d36ef0b6f1bc5159525b145a925a) from [Ryan Florence](https://github.com/ryanflorence) that's the basis for the above hack:

```
if (
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' &&
  window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ &&
  Object.keys(window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__._renderers).length
) {
  window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__._renderers = {}
}
```

---

**Update:** React 16 has a new console warning that reads `Warning: The installed version of React DevTools is too old and will not work with the current version of React. Please update React DevTools`. To disable it, put this code in the global scope:

```
__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = {
  supportsFiber: true,
  inject: function() {},
  onCommitFiberRoot: function() {},
  onCommitFiberUnmount: function() {},
};
```

Comment: where exactly in storybook config files do you add it? I tried in `priview-head.html` by adding it inside `<script>` tag, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

Put something like that in your html

```
<script>{`
  (function() {
    var info = console.info
    console.info = function (message) {
      if (!/Download the React DevTools/.test(message)) info.apply(console, arguments) 
    }
  })()
`}</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Here's a solution for Next.JS (works with 12.1.6 at time of writing):

In your project root, add the following lines to `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // add your other next config settings here
  webpack: (
      config,
    { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack }
  ) => {
    config.plugins = [...config.plugins,
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        '__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__': '({ isDisabled: true })'
      })
    ]
    // Important: return the modified config
    return config
  },
}
```

This solution combines [Dan Abramov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48324794/4280615) with the [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) description of modifying webpack config.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Storybook with Angular or Vue, or any other framework - the message  **"Download the React DevTools for a better development experience:"** in the devtools does't make any sense. And even for folks who use React - it may be annoying.
I tried all answers in this thread, however, they don't really work anymore. Even the accepted answer is no valid anymore. So, this is what works right now for **Storybook 6+** and **Webpack 4/5:**

- The message comes from the Storybook Manager (which is created with React I guess). Create file `manager.js` in your `.storybook` dir. It should be a sibling of your other storybook config files, e.g. main.js, privew.js, etc..
- Add the following code to disable a range of React messages:

  ```
   // .storybook/manager.js
   window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = {
       _renderers: {},
       supportsFiber: true,
       inject: () => ({}),
       onCommitFiberRoot: () => ({}),
       onCommitFiberUnmount: () => ({}),
   };
  ```

Re-run your build and the message should disappear. This will also remove another warning from React: **The installed version of React DevTools is too old and will not work with the current version of React**

Answer (score -9):

Also, locally you could just comment that part of code.

Search all file in "node_modules" for "React DevTools", you will get 2 results, react-dom.js and ReactDOM.js:

- react-dom.js, navigate to line 5430, make line 5430 - 5437 to a comment, save.
- ReactDOM.js, navigate to line 68, make line 68 - 75 to a comment, save.

Restart your app server.

I hope this method is not against the React License.

Comment: Pls never do this.

Comment: Method is effective and feels satisfying. +1

Comment: That's what I wanted to do.. but people are against it..

Comment: @Liban I am now not sure they all against to remove it though, more likely they against this solution. it is not a good solution, re-edit is needed everytime after update the package, besides the lines number could be different then.