# How disable message in console "Download the React DevTools" in React 18

Tags: reactjs, console, react-devtools

How disable message in console "Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
" in React v.18 without install this app in browser?

Comment: solutions from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196819/disable-hide-download-the-react-devtools dont work

Comment: this lib https://github.com/naoufal/disable-react-devtools dont work